# why does my substr not work properly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following code:

```
var serverTime ="October 01, 2015 18:39:21 +0900";
var timezone = serverTime.substr(serverTime.length-5,serverTime.length-1);
alert(timezone);
```

and I want to display +09, however in a return I get the full string +0900. Why does my substr function not return the correct value?

http://jsfiddle.net/8ej2kwte/

Comment: Use `substring` as `serverTime.substring(serverTime.length-5,serverTime.length-2);` Check updated http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8ej2kwte/1/

Comment: simple answer ... second parameter is a LENGTH

Comment: Exactly as Jaromanda X said, before asking a question related to a specific function, it's recommended to [know its syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substr() method extracts parts of a string, beginning at the character at the specified position, and returns the specified number of characters.

```
var serverTime ="October 01, 2015 18:39:21 +0900";
var timezone = serverTime.substr(serverTime.length-5,3);
alert(timezone);
```

Answer (score 2):

[From MDN substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

> `str.substr(start[, length])`
>
> Parameters
>
> `start`
>
> Location at which to begin extracting characters. If a negative number
>   is given, it is treated as strLength + start where strLength is the
>   length of the string (for example, if start is -3 it is treated as
>   strLength - 3.)
>
> `length` Optional.
>
> The number of characters to extract.

With substr, the second parameter is the length of the string to extract, not the end position. So you should be using `3` as the second parameter. Also look into [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) which uses indexes.